# Alternative to Axis function for reading Filter in mDX

Tags: mdx

AXIS function in MDX cannot be used to check what is on the Filter - WHERE clause. has someone tried an alternative to this so that we could read which fields are on the where clause?

Thanks
Rakesh

Answer (score 0):

you could use the Existing function to get the members of one specific dimension. 
Example:

```
With member [measures].[members] as SetToStr(EXISTING [Product].[Category].[Category])
Select
  {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount], [measures].[members]} on columns,
  {[Customer].[Customer Geography].[State-Province]} on rows
From [Adventure Works]
Where ({[Product].[Category].&[4], [Product].[Category].&[1]})
```

Regards.

Comment: thanks for the reply Noe, Just saw this and i am yet to try it out it works fine basically my requirement is With member [measures].[members] as SetToStr(EXISTING [Product].[Category].[Category])
Select
  {[Product].[Category].&[4], [Product].[Category].&[1]} on columns,
  {[Customer].[Customer Geography].[State-Province]} on rows
From [Adventure Works]
Where [Measures].[members] and for each of the columns the result of Measure.Members should be same "[Product].[Category].&[4], [Product].[Category].&[1]".anyway shall try EXISTING function and see it help. thanks